# What does serde deserialize dashes to?

Tags: json, rust, serde

For a project I'm working on I have to implement a struct for serde to deserialize some JSON data into. The other guys on the project have expressed their great desire that a certain field of the struct be an enum.

Unfortunately, it turns out that one of the possible values in the JSON includes a “-” character. Insofar as I have been able to determine, enum variants can't have dashes in their names.

How do I deserialize data that might contain dashes? I tried looking through the serde documentation, but haven't been able to find anything.

Here's an example of the kind of data I'm talking about:

```json
{
    "fubar": "foo-bar"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`#[serde(rename)]`](https://serde.rs/variant-attrs.html#rename):

```rust
enum Foo {
    #[serde(rename = "foo-bar")]
    FooBar,
}
```